# Finding the best $k-$subset which maximizes a matrix sum

Tags: optimization, time-complexity

Let $M\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ be a given matrix and $k\ge 2$ be a given integer. Then my question is the following optimization problem:

Is there a polynomial-time solution to the following problem: $$S^\star = \arg\max_{S\subset [N]:\\ |S|\le k} \sum_{i,j\in S}M_{ij}.$$

This seems to be hard in general (that is, it requires exponential time-complexity), but I could not find a direct link to any known problem. I first thought that this problem is related to the maximum subset problem, but I am not sure. It will be really helpful if somebody can provide any reference to any related problem. It seems that approximate solutions can be found for this problem, but I was unable to find that too after a Google search. It will be really great if someone can give any reference.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: WLOG you can assume $M$ is symmetric (because the term $M_{ij}$ is counted iff the term $M_{ji}$ is counted).  So the problem is equivalent to the following: given a graph with (possibly negative) edge weights, find a subset of at most $k$ vertices that maximizes the total weight of the edges in the induced subgraph.  In the case that $M$ is a symmetric 0/1 matrix, this is equivalent to the [densest $k$-subgraph problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_subgraph#Densest_k_subgraph), which is NP-hard as it generalizes CLIQUE.  (And see the wikipedia link for more details.)

Comment: asked simultaneously and answered on mathoverflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405318/finding-a-k-subset-which-maximizes-a-matrix-sum

Comment: p.s. The link to the densest subgraph problem discusses approximation algorithms including hardness of approximation.

Comment: Thanks for the very informative comments!